# How to install composer globally for laravel app in windows?

Tags: laravel

I have a question related to composer and laravel. My question is whenever I install the fresh laravel app using command :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog
```

Inside my `C://xampp/htdocs/` directory and then change path to `C://xampp/htdocs/blog/`, here I am unable to run the composer command but I had already installed composer from its official website globally in `C://xampp/htdocs/` directory. So is there any way to use composer command globally whenever I install fresh laravel app, so that I don't want to install composer in the laravel app directory everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Now I guess they provide direct setting up global installation, 
Check [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)

I did it like this a lot earlier,

Change to the path (or you can add that directory to your path later), and run the installer as mentioned on [composer download site](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to download `composer.phar`.
Create a new `composer.bat` file alongside `composer.phar`.
Using cmd.exe:
run

```
echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

Then set it to path environment variable([see this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm))
Test with a new terminal:

```
composer -V
```

Will return

```
Composer version 1.10.6 2020-05-06 10:28:10
```

Answer (score 0):

go to [composer website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows) and download the exe file, you should have it gloablly if you install it that way.

Good luck ^_^